# Eclipse SVN not working correctly on Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, svn, compatibility, windows-10, subversive

I recently moved from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and I'm having some issues with Eclipse when I try to import/share a project by using SVN. I'm not actually getting any error. When I try to import a project, eclipse keeps "thinking" as the image below

[image]

I've been waiting for hours but nothing happens. I tried with many eclipse distributions, Mars, Kepler, STS.

I tried to import the same project from another PC with Windows 7 and didn't have any issue.

Any ideas what's going on? I also tried to set the compatibility to Windows 7 as the image below

[image]

I'm using Eclipse Subversive and SVN Kit 1.7.14

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check windows firewall settings if eclipse is allowed on your network : `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall\Allowed apps` (it's for win 8 but should be ~same for  10)

Comment: I tried that but didn't work either